# Call JS function from Codebehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use this code for call JS function from codebehind.

This is button click event.

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "myfunction", "testFunc();", true);
```

This is the code of JS.

```
function testFunc() {
//alert("msg");
document.getElementById("Text1").value = "value change";
//Text1 is html a text box
}
```

It's not change the value of the text box. But if i add alert, it is showing the alert which we can identify that the JS function is executing successfully.

What could be the problem of my code?

Comment: Please could you post your HTML/ASP code?

Comment: For testing purposes try js alert() function because some html controls are usinh InnerHtml instead of value

Answer (score 0):

If document.getElementById("Text1") is textarea tag, use

```
document.getElementById("Text1").innerText = "value change";
```

Could you provie HTML for clarification?

Comment: <div id="draggable" class="ui-icon-image">
   <img id="img1" src="/Resource/location_icon.png" width="27px" height="45px" />
</div>
    
<input id="Text1" type="text" runat="server" name="htmlText" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click1" />

Comment: Actually showing some value through codebehind is one requirment. And the other way it is needed to move the img in runtime. Thats why I try to execute JS function from codebehind.
This is my requirment exacly.

1. Change html text box value after clicking asp button.
2. Change the location of the img controller, executing C sharp function. (CS functions can send X,Y coordinates as paramenters.)

How to do this? I just thought using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript can do this. But seems like it's bit difficult.

Comment: Im sorry about the comments which cant add new line for it and cant add my comments to ANSWER option since I don't have much reputation points for doing it.

Comment: Are there some errors in browser console? Maybe element with id="Text1" does not exists, to check it try `alert(document.getElementById("Text1"))` or `console.log(document.getElementById("Text1"))` in browser console(F12), if message in is null, element does not exists.

Comment: Yes. I tried it. Message has nothing. But how to say that element does not exist? My html code has it as I show in 1st comment in here. Please tell me, what could be the issue in this?

Comment: Html code in 1st comment is code on server side. Seems that ASP modify html before send it to browser on client. Sorry, but i know about ASP nothing, i only can assume attribute `runat="server"` is waste, try without it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not accessing the HTML Textbox via codebehind?

Use this to insert a value to a textbox:

```
Request.Form["yourHTMLTBName"] = "new Value inserted";
```

Decleration in HTML:

```
<input id="tbHTML" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="yourHTMLTBName"/>
```

Try to make it static: `ClientIDMode="Static"`

Comment: I tried this. But It is shown this error 'An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code'